# issues debugging polymer straight from IDE/edit tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, polymer, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I am quite new to Polymer and I would like to be able to debug projects straight from one IDE. I mean, instead of using Chrome debugger, I would prefer debug from Visual Studio Code or Sublime or Atom or another tool (kindly, there is no interest in this question to compare the IDEs available. I just want some way to debug from any IDE).

All subjects I have read so far didn't me drive to any real tutorial which could help me. The only one I found I couldn't make it run.

I followed https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/debug-polymer-tests-with-vs-code-7646d66d0608 and when I try Run WCT I get Attribute 'program' doesn't exist.

My launch.json is

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run wct",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\my-company-component.html",
      "args": [
        "-p",
        "--skip-plugin", "local",
        "--plugin", "none",
        "--webserver-port", "2000",
        "--expanded",
        "--simpleOutput", "${workspaceFolder}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run chrome for wct",
      "url": "http://localhost:2000/components/my-company-component/generated-index.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome"
    }
  ]
}
```

Today, I have been using gulp to start a local server and then debug using Chrome but, in case it is possible use an IDE + some extension/plugin I would prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

program should be either 'wct' if you installed it with -g or
 "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/wct" if you installed it locally using npm.
That should solve your error, I did not get the other parts to work still though..

Answer (score 0):

Well, after several tentatives and searching for while, I assume that the only way to debug is by using Chrome. I mean, I didn't find any efficient way to debug using Visual Studio Code, Atom or other IDE. I will consider https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3635 as an answer to my question.